# Sprites won't show in scene, but code says, that is does

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, load, scene

I'm almost done with my game, that I've worked on for 5 months. Now I'm dealing with Save&Load system.  Everything works except loading item sprites. I have a collection of instances(items), which saves and loads correctly. **The problem is in loading the sprites into the inventory slots.**

I have a function, that is called after successful load. There is much more load code, but it ain't important for this issue. The thing is that I load collection of ingots into static class, where all my data is. After that I call function, that is supposed to load the sprites based on that collection data.

```
    private void setData(Data _data)
    {
        Pdata.MaterialIngots = _data.materialIngots;

        LoadItemSprites();
    }
```

I start with foreach to run through all ingots in game. I **successfully** load the sprite. After that I load the slots into gameObjects array (The order of slots doesn't matter). After that I run though this array using foreach.
Every slot has script, that has uniqued index. And every slot has one child - Image. So if slot index and object index matches - there should be the sprite.
**Sprite loading** itself doesn't look that hard. I just take the parent gameobject (go.transform) and get the first child (.GetChild(0)) then I need Image component of that child (GetComponent()) and its sprite (.sprite). At the end I have to enable the slot to actually see it. This all happends **successfully**. At last, the Log says so. Properties of previously changed gameobject are **not changed**. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Please help.. I really want ot finish this :(..

[image: Debug.Log output image]
[image: Image not changed properties]

```
    private void LoadItemSprites()
    {
        foreach (MaterialIngot mingot in Pdata.MaterialIngots)
        {
            //load sprite
            Sprite thisSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(mingot.Path);
            if (thisSprite == null) break;
            gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(mingot.Location + "Inventory");// as GameObject;
            Debug.Log(gameObjects.Length);
            //load sprite into location + index !!
            foreach (GameObject go in gameObjects)
            {
                if (go.GetComponent<SlotHandler>().index == mingot.LocationIndex)
                {
                    Debug.Log(go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite);
                    go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = thisSprite;
                    Debug.Log(go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                    Debug.Log(go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled);
                    go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
                    Debug.Log(go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are all your objects active? Maybe the log is from a different GameObject, not the one you are looking at? Also use `GetComponent` only **once** and store the reference! Also try `if(!this sprite)` instead .. unity `Object` is often not exactly `null` but stores some meta data

Comment: In general: Do **not** use `Resources` at all! Rather drag the textures/sprites into proper `public Sprite[] sprites;` fields via the Inspector

Comment: Unfortunately, we would need to see your actual hierarchy to give more information.  I have no idea where this object is located or if it is a child of one of the objects...  the other issue is as derHugo stated, I can't see if the object is active or not.

Comment: Can you also show us your FULL log not just a snip of it.  we cant tell if there are other errors that could be cause problems such as a null reference somewhere (like in one of your getChild calls or getComponent calls that you should be storing and checking if theyh arent null)

Comment: Are you sure `go.transform.GetChild(0)` return the correct `GameObject` ? Can you log it ?

Comment: I solved it.. I'm oficially dumb. Before I tell you I'll answer to your questions. Thank you for your responses everyone.

My objects are active. The log, that I'm looking at is good. I will store the GetComponent only once. I promise :D.

I don't see any problem in using Resources. It works and was recomended by many ppl to me.

I'm sorry that I didn't involve the actual hierarchy. Because I'm using tags, I thought it wouldn't be any useful. The objects are active.

That was whole log, that I snipped. 

Yes, I'm sure and I logged it.

Comment: I was calling the method in wrong scene (MainMenu). I was supposed to call it after the Game scene is loaded -> on Start method. It's strange that it loaded the gameobjects, but what I think happened is, that it changed it's values and then rewrited the default settings of every object.